# Box Push Game Trouble with Slick2d

Tags: java, collision-detection, slick2d

I am using Slick2d to create a game where a character "Larry" pushes a "Box" around a map of a pre-defined size. I have no trouble drawing a picture over an entity and getting its position to update with the entity when it moves.

My main issue is that I cannot find a way for my collision detection methods to stop any movement. Currently when a collision is detected nothing happens. When I try to directly use a collision detection method in my movement statements, eclipse says that there are no entities.

---

```
public abstract class Entity {

protected int x, y, w, h, dx, dy;

public Entity(int x, int y) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;
    w = 32;
    h = 32;
}

public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

}

public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) throws SlickException {

    /*x += dx;
    y += dy;*/
}

public boolean isLeftCollision(Entity entity) {
    if (this.x == entity.x && this.y == entity.y) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isRightCollision(Entity entity) {
    if (this.x + this.w == entity.x && this.y == entity.y) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isTopCollision(Entity entity) {
    if (this.y == entity.y && this.x == entity.x) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isBottomCollision(Entity entity) {
    if (this.y + this.h == entity.y && this.x == entity.x) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

---

```
public class Larry extends Entity{
Image player;
float speed = 0.2f;

public Larry(float x, float y) {
    super((int) x, (int) y);

    w = 32;
    h = 32;

}

public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException{

    super.render(gc, g);
    player = new Image("res/char/LarryUP.png");
    g.drawImage(player, x, y);
    g.drawString("Characters X: " + x + "\nCharacters Y: " + y, speed,
            speed);     
}

public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) throws SlickException{

    super.update(gc, delta);
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    //move right
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)) {
        x += speed * delta;
        if (x > 782) {
            x -= speed * delta;
        }
    }
    //move left
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)) {
        x -= speed * delta;
        if (x < 0) {
            x += speed * delta;
        }
    }
    //move down
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)) {
        y += speed * delta;
        if (y > 585) {
            y -= speed * delta;
        }
    }
    //move up
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {
        y -= speed * delta;
        if (y < 0) {
            y += speed * delta;
        }
    } 
}
```

---

```
public class PlayState extends BasicGameState {
int stateID = 3;
Image background;
Larry larry;
Packages box;
float x = 400.0f;
float y = 300.0f;
float speed = 0.2f;
boolean quit = false;

public PlayState(int stateID) {

    this.stateID = stateID;

}

@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg1)
        throws SlickException {
    background = new Image("background.jpg");
    larry = new Larry(400,300);
    box = new Packages(150,300);
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g)
        throws SlickException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
    larry.render(gc, g);
    box.render(gc, g);

    if (quit == true) {
        g.drawString("Resume (R)", 250, 100);
        g.drawString("Main Menu (M)", 250, 125);
        g.drawString("Quit Game (Q)", 250, 150);
        if (quit == false) {
            g.clear();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)
        throws SlickException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    // escape
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
        quit = true;
    }
    // when they hit escape
    if (quit == true) {
        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_R)) {
            quit = false;
        }
        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_M)) {
            sbg.enterState(0);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_Q)) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    larry.update(gc, delta);
    box.update(gc, delta);
}

@Override
public int getID() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3;
}
```

}

---

```
public class Packages extends Entity{
Image box;
float speed = 0.2f;

public Packages(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);

    w = 32;
    h = 32; 
}

    public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException{

    super.render(gc, g);
    box = new Image("res/obj/box1.png");
    g.drawImage(box, x, y);
}

public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) throws SlickException{

    super.update(gc, delta);
}
}
```

---

If you have any ideas or can offer any help please let me know. I have been looking online for several days and have talked with several others, but no one seems to have a concrete idea of what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use your Collision Method,
In your update method of the class Larry, put a condition, if there is a collision don't bother move your player

(example when you're trying to move down

```
if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {
        if(isBottomCollision(this)) {
             y -= speed * delta;
             if (y < 0) {
                 y += speed * delta;
             }
        }
    }
```

like this, if the player try to go down but there is a collision, he will not be able to move.
You can make only one method to get collision with an extra arguments (an Enum) or two (x and y) which told the method which way the player is trying to go

```
Direction {LEFT, RIGHT, UP,DOWN} //global
public boolean isCollision(Entity entity, direction direction)
```

or

```
public boolean isCollision(Entity entity,int x, int y)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do: 
    this.x == entity.x && this.y == entity.y
it will only take 1 point of the image/collision and not the whole left side

what you gotta do is draw a shape (Rectangle, Cirlce, Polygon etc.) around it
and use the intersects() method like this:

```
Rectangle entityCollision;
Rectangle boxCollision;

public Entity() {
    //your code here
}

public void init(arguments){
    entityCollision = new Rectangle(arguments);
    boxCollision = new Rectangle(arguments);
}

public void render(arguments){
    //your code here
}

public void update(arguments){

    if(entityCollision.intersects(boxCollision)){
        //this is where the computer checks the collision
        //your code here
    }

}
```